# Django query with order_by, distinct and limit on Postgresql

Tags: django, postgresql, django-queryset

I have the following :

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Action(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I would like to retrieve the 10 most recent actions ordered by created_at DESC with distinct products.

The following is close to the result but still misses the ordering:

```
Action.objects.all().order_by('product_id').distinct('product_id')[:10]
```

Comment: Have you tried reversing the order of your `order_by()` and `distinct()` calls?

Comment: Django's documentation states: "When you specify field names, you must provide an order_by() in the QuerySet, and the fields in order_by() must start with the fields in distinct(), in the same order.". https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct

Comment: Your order by `product_id`, rather than `created_at`. Why?

Comment: Because in order to have distinct('product_id') works you have to specify it in the order_by clause.

Comment: You can, however, have multiple arguments to order_by. According to their examples with the link you just provided, it appears you could do: `.order_by('product_id', 'created_at').distinct('product_id')`

Comment: Yes, but this will order by product_id and then by created_at which won't lead to the expected result

Comment: I'm not entirely certain that's true (but of course I could be wrong.) Their last example does precisely that: `Entry.objects.order_by('author', 'pub_date').distinct('author')`

Comment: This won't work. In your example it will order by author and among those pick the oldest Entry. In your example we want the oldest Entries ordered by pub_date.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your solution seems like it's trying to do too much. It will also result in 2 separate SQL queries. This would work fine and with only a single query:

```
action_ids = Action.objects.order_by('product_id', '-created_at')\
    .distinct('product_id').values_list('id', flat=True)

result = Action.objects.filter(id__in=action_ids)\
    .order_by('-created_at')[:10]
```

Comment: Using `values_list' is a good idea since it saves one query. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Have you tried running my code? The first line will run fine as both the first `order_by` and `distinct` are the same. The first `-created_at` ensures you will only get the latest action for each product (at this point they would be in the wrong order). The second line just puts the actions in the correct order but still keeps it in the same query.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, you are right ! Your code works perfectly and is better than mine ! thanks :)

Comment: I still don't get why we can't do this in only one line like `Action.objects.order_by('product_id', '-created_at').distinct('product_id')[:10]`. I am saying that because I am trying to use `.distinct(...).filter(...)` and it seems that the filter is "executed" before the distinct...

Answer (score 6):

**EDIT: this solution works but Ross Lote's is cleaner**

This is the way I finally did it, using [Django Aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/):

```
from django.db.models import Max
    
actions_id = Action.objects.all().values('product_id') \
    .annotate(action_id=Max('id')) \
    .order_by('-action_id')[:10] \
    .values_list('action_id', flat=True)

result = Action.objects.filter(id__in=actions_id).order_by('-created_at')
```

By setting `values('product_id')` we do a **group by** on **product_id**.

With `annotate()` we can use **order_by** only on fields used in `values()` or `annotate()`. Since for each action the **created_at** field is automatically set to now, ordering on **created_at** is the same as ordering on **id**, using `annotate(action_id=Max('id')).order_by('-action_id')` is the right way.

Finnaly, we just need to slice our query `[:10]`

Hope this helps.