# Query excluding duplicates in Django

Tags: django

I'm using [`distinct()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) QuerySet to get some data in Django.
My initial query was `Point.objects.order_by('chron', 'pubdate')`.
The field `chron` in some cases is a duplicate so I changed the query
to `Point.objects.order_by('chron', 'pubdate').distinct('chron')` in order to exclude duplicates.
Now the problem is that all empty fields are considered duplicates.

To be accurate, the `chron` field contain integers (which behave similar to ids), in some cases it can be a duplicate, in some cases it can be NULL.

```
| chron |
|-------|
| 1     | I want this
| 2     | I want this
| 3     | I want this
| 3     |
| NULL  |
| 4     | I want this
| NULL  |
```

I want to exclude all the `chron` duplicates but not if they are duplicate of NULL.
Thank you.

Comment: check this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30084107/django-query-with-order-by-distinct-and-limit-on-postgresql. then do exclude to filter null result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use two separate queries.

- `.distinct("chron").exclude(chron__isnull=True)`
- `.filter()` for only `chron` values where `chron__isnull=True`.

Although this seems pretty inefficient I believe (I will happily be corrected) that even any sensible vanilla SQL statement (eg. below) would require multiple table scans to join a result set of nulls and unique values.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT chron
    FROM Point
    WHERE chron IS NOT NULL  # .exclude()
    GROUP BY chron  # .distinct()

    UNION ALL

    SELECT chron
    FROM Point
    WHERE chron IS NULL  # .include()
)
```

Comment: why would you do `GROUP BY` instead of `SELECT DISTINCT`?

Comment: Thanks, it worked with a little adjustment: `chron__isnull` instead of `chron__is_null`, I think because `chron` is an `IntegerField`.

Comment: I'll update the answer with the corrected syntax. Make sure to mark you question as answered.

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev I looked into this since I originally did it out of habit. As per this answer here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/581521/whats-faster-select-distinct-or-group-by-in-mysql) DISTINCT is better to use when grouping by a non-indexed column.