# Get distinct django objects from queryset sorted by latest

Tags: django, filter, sql-order-by, django-queryset, distinct

I have this model (irrelevant fields hidden):

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, default=None, blank=True)
```

I only want to get the latest post of each author, sorted by published date.

I have tried the following in my view:

```
blog_list = Blog.objects.filter(
    is_published=True
).order_by('author', '-published_date').distinct('author')
```

Which works *except* this sorts all of the blog post in order of the author, not by published date.

The following would actually do the trick by switching the order by, but this throws an error in django:

```
blog_list = Blog.objects.filter(
    is_published=True
).order_by('-published_date', 'author').distinct('author')
```

I've checked all of the similar questions to this one and haven't encountered a solution that works. I think this request should be pretty simple but I don't see any way of achieving this.

Comment: this looks like it involves 2 models, I've seen similar questions like this and it wasn't applicable to my question. I'll check it out and test though.

Comment: Try this from django.db.models import Max
Blog.objects.filter(pk__in=Blog.objects.order_by('-published_date').
                        values('auther_id').annotate(
        max_id=Max('pk')).values('max_id'), is_publish=true)

Comment: @GorkhaliKhadka This looks like it almost does the trick! I do see some unique author posts. However I'm encountering issues such as: not all authors are showing up, and the blog posts are not sorted by their published date

Comment: Do you solve your problem or not?

Comment: @GorkhaliKhadka Thank you, yes it was resolved with the answer I posted, but I cannot choose a best answer for two days. I will try out other solutions and see if they do it better.

Comment: I also added another answer did you try this? that;s works fine for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to get this to work using the following:

```
blog_ids = Blog.objects.filter(is_published = True)\
.order_by('author_id', '-published_date')\
.distinct('author_id')\
.values('id', flat=True)

blog_list = Blog.objects.filter(id__in=blog_ids)\
.order_by('-published_date')
```

Which gets exactly what I wanted!!!!

More detail on this method can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32760239/2990550

Comment: In my case I had to ommit `flat=True` to get it work

Answer (score 1):

You can read this post in official [Djang documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#distinct).
Based on this post, **when you specify field names in distinct clause, you must provide an order_by() in the QuerySet, and the fields in order_by() must start with the fields in distinct(), in the same order.** To get the goal you said above, following this :

```
from django.db.models import Max
blog_list = Blog.objects.filter(is_published=True).values('author').annotate(Max('published_date'))
```

Comment: I get the error: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'group_by'

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

```
blog_list = Blog.objects.filter(is_published=True).distinct('author').order_by('-published_date', 'author')
```

Comment: doesn't work, this would sort the blog posts correctly, but it would show all the posts of the authors. I only want the author's latest post.

Comment: I get an error when using the updated answer, same as the error generated using the second line I posted in the question

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this:

```
Blog.objects.filter(is_published=True).order_by('-published_date').order_by('author').distinct('author')
```

It will give what you want.
here you will get all authors latest blogs.

Comment: Awesome idea, I really thought this would work, but after trying it, it just does the same thing as:

blog_list = Blog.objects.filter(is_published=True).order_by('author', '-published_date').distinct('author')

Comment: I am using this and i am getting correct data: Appointments.objects.all().order_by('-date').order_by('user_id').distinct('user_id')  I dont know where the problem is with you.

Comment: Are you sure this is not giving the same result as: Appointments.objects.all().order_by('user_id', '-date').distinct('user_id')? That is what it does for me

Comment: I am using Postgresql so maybe the SQL is rendered differently

Comment: Dude i am also using PSQL

Comment: When I used it, it yielded the same results as Blog.objects.filter(is_published=True).order_by('author', '-published_date').distinct('author') which I already stated I tried and was not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code 
Now this is remove null values

```
from django.db.models import Max

Blog.objects.filter(pk__in=Blog.objects.order_by('-published_date').values(
        'author_id').annotate(max_id=Max('pk')).values('max_id'),
                        is_published=True, author_id__isnull=False).order_by('-author_id')
```